Why is my spice model not working?
I am encountering a strange problem. I tried downloading a spice model for DMC2450UV NMOS/PMOS complementary transistor array but it doesn't open in LTSPICE. I get an error that says

could not open include file DMC2450UV.txt.

I saved the file to the same path directory as my LTSPICE schematic. I saved a different transistor model into the same working directory and tried opening it in the same file and it worked. This leads me to believe something may be wrong with the file. I got it from this website.

Verify that you saved the file DMC2450UV.txt in the path directory of your LTspice project. Your web reference indicates that you had downloaded the file DMC2450UV.spice.txt.

Here’s a cleaner link, but V.V.T’s comment still applies. https://www.diodes.com/spice/download/2134/DMC2450UV.spice.txt

All I can say with absolute certainty is that the models work perfectly. N Channel : https://imgur.com/4vTGS36 P Channel: https://imgur.com/ZhSbVJY

did you remove .spice and make it DMC2450.txt?

I made it DMC2450.txt but this didn't fix the problem. I can't use the model still.

Do you get the same error or a different one now?

the extension is somehow messing things up. @ste kulov I used the file you provided and in the .op directive, i used ".inc DMC2450UV.spice.txt" instead of ".inc DMC2450UV.txt" and the message didn't show up. Instead another message showed up that says "can't find definition of model "dmc24550_n"

@ste kulov the link you provided looks the same as the one i used. is there a difference?

It’s not the same. Mine is a direct link. Yours was a Google re-direct. But I don’t think that matters. I think your current problem requires you to read this article: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

The solution in the article you mentioned didn't work for me. I really don't know what is going on. Your article linked to another article that:https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html
This article gave an alternative method that worked. The only downside is that the symbol looks like a block that pairs with the netlist ports instead of the nice looking transistor symbols I wanted.

I think the link to the guide given by Ste Kulov is quite clear on how to get it to work. I am pretty sure you either did not follow the steps fully or make some mistakes along the way. I followed the steps and got it working.

